# Would someone be able to identify this language and translate the text to english?

Tags: english, indo-european, written-language

I just bought this bracelet at a random goodwill shop in Boston and it's beautiful, I would just like to make sure I'm not wearing something offensive or religiously significant. [image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you flip it over, you'll see that it's Devanagari, and therefore an Indian language.

Answer (score 6):

I rotated your image 180°. The letters are not Devanagari, they are Tibetan, and the language is Sanskrit, it is the famous Buddhist mantra **Om mani padme hum**, read about its meaning here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_mani_padme_hum